# Generating Binomial binary numbers with arbitrary probability in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I can easily generate a sequence of binary numbers whose elements have the same probability. In other words,

- Pr("1") = 0.5 and Pr("0") = 0.5

Now, I want to create a sequence of binary numbers whose elements can take an arbitrary probability, to say

- Pr("1") = p and Pr("0") = 1-p

How can I do that? Is there any exclusive command for generating this in Matlab? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
P = desired_prob_of_zero;   % e.g., 0.1;
N = number_of_samples;
x = rand(N,1) < P;
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. I was wondering if I can generate it through writing a single command.

Comment: You can do it all in the final line by hardcoding `N` and `P`, but that doesn't make it very extensible in the future. Do you have a character limit (e.g. coding for Twitter)?

Comment: Yes, my intention was to find the most compact way. However, I don't have a strict obligation for that.

Comment: Put it in a function.

Comment: @Cardinal This already _is_ a single statement (third line). You could also use `x = binornd(1,P,[1 N]);` but that requires the Statistics Toolbox and is probably slower

Comment: @LuisMendo I know, exactly I don't want to use any specific tool-boxes such as Mupad or something.